# unable to retrieve request param in node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

In my angular js factory, i am making an ajax call to transfer the input model value to the server side ( node js) but when i try to retrieve it , i see 'undefined' .

angular js :

```
angular.module('name-App').factory('myService', function($http,$rootScope) {

   return {

        getFoos: function(stock) {
            console.log("----------->"+stock.toString());//displays the value correctly over here .
             //return the promise directly.
             return  $http({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/gethistorydata', 
        method: "GET",
        params: stock
     }).then(function(result) {


                            alert("result.data"+result.data);
                            return result.data;
                        }).catch(function(fallback) {
    alert("failed"+fallback + '!!');
  });
        }
   }
});
```

In node js i have below :

```
app.get('/gethistorydata',function(req,res){
console.log("--------------->>>>>>");

console.log("stock name = "+req.params.data);
    //res.cookie();
//res.sendFile("F:/customer/public/index.html");
});
```

req.params.data is undefined . whats wrong with syntax?

Answer (score 1):

`req.params` refers to url path parameters. So you would have to add one to your route for it to be supported. For example a request to `/gethistorydata/123` with this route defined(note the added `/:id` on the end):

```
app.get('/gethistorydata/:id, function(req, res) {
  console.log('my id is ' + req.params.id');
});
```

would log "my id is 123".

I think you are looking for `req.query`. What does your `stock` object look like? If it looked like this `{"price": 123}` angular would modify the request to look like `/gethistorydata?price=123` and you could change your code to this:

```
app.get('/gethistorydata, function(req, res) {
  console.log('my stock price is ' + req.query.price');
});
```

which would log "my stock price is 123"

See the docs for more examples http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

Comment: my param is like params: {st:stock} where stock is in format  nse:storeone , this is giving me error in console.http://localhost:3000/gethistorydata?st=nse:storeone 404 (Not Found)  how should i send "nse:storeone " as a single value so that semicolon is not disregarded.